# In kivy using screenmanager how can I add other widgets like scatter?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm developing kivy app.
While I'm using `ScreenManager`, I can only add `Screen` in to it.
But `Screen` seems that it can add other widgets.
How can I add scatter widget  to `Screen` for interface performance?

```
class sc(Scatter):
    pass
class Screen1(Screen):
    pass
class Screen2(Screen):
    pass
class manager(ScreenManager):
    pass
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = manager()
        s1 = Screen1()
        sca = sc()

        s1.add_widget(sca)
        sm.add_widget(s1)

        return sm

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code *does* add a Scatter (what you call `sca`) to a Screen (what you call `s1`).